# how to reduce memory usage of OHAttributedLabel and drawTextInRect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uilabel

I am using OHAttributedLabel in my custom UITableViewCell and I tried profiling the app as it seems that the app is uses the memory like sane. So here's what I found out:

[image]

Any ideas on how to reduce this memory consumption?
Also in the library it has a method on to calculate the height of the text, but for some reason it is one of the heaviest stack trace based on instruments:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is just because is creating his drawing contenxt, try to reduce the label size and you should see lower memory, anyway after the drawing operation the context should be released and becomes part of the memory of the full layer. I mean what's the overall app memory allocation after building the table view ?

Comment: well it's also one operation which takes quite some time, judging from the time profiler

Comment: I do believe but that method is an Apple implementation to create a frame setter after that it usually comes drawing of the text. Here is used to do metrics, maybe is a little bit wasted but I can't find anything wrong. Maybe is not correct the pattern, just think that probably in your table view the text view size is almost fixed and you are doing this operation for each row and of course this is a waste of resources.